# Is point $A$ located in part of a circle in three dimensional space?

Tags: geometry

Given a point $A(x_a,y_a,z_a)$, a circle $O((x_O,y_O,z_O),r)$, and an circular sector $BOC$ constructed by two rays $\vec{OB}$ and $\vec{OC}$ starting from the center $(x_O,y_O,z_O)$ where the angle between the two rays is $160^\circ$, what's the formula to let a computer know if point $A$ is located in the area?

Comment: Please add your own thoughts !

Comment: One may assume the lengths of segments $OB,\ OC$ are each $r$ to make algebra simpler. Is that OK for your application? Also when you say "an area BOC" does it mean the circular sector or the triangle?

Comment: @coffeemath it's circular sector, and that's ok with whatever length of $OB
$ and $OC$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ß_1$ represents the angle between $\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{OB}$, $ß_2$ represents the angle between $\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{OC}$, $∂$ represents the angle between $\vec{OB}$ and $\vec{OC}$.

$∂ = ß_1 + ß_2$ if $\vec{OA}$ between $\vec{OB}$ and $\vec{OC}$,

with the addition identity: $cos(A+B)=cosA•cosB-sinA•sinB$,

1) point $A$ locate in the triangle $BOC$ if $cos∂ = cosß_1•cosß_2 - sinß_1•sinß_2$.

2) point A is located in circle O if $|\vec{OA}|<=r$.

points meet (1) and (2) are located in the circular sector $BOC$.

Use dot product to calculate $cosß_1$ and $cosß_2$:

$cosß_1 = \vec{OA}•\vec{OB}/(|\vec{OA}|•|\vec{OB}|)$

$cosß_2 = \vec{OA}•\vec{OC}/(|\vec{OA}|•|\vec{OC}|)$